# What is the opposite of the PHP function date()?

Tags: php

Is there any function in PHP that either takes a date and turns it into a time stamp, or can simply take a date in one format and change it into another format? I have a set of dates in the format 'm d', which I want to change to 'l, F d, Y'.

I will need this with dates in other formats as well, so a function that lets me give it a date, input format and output format.

Comment: single() that's fairly opposite of any type of dating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

> Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format

For output in a new format you have

[`DateTime::format`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Or for a timestamp

[`DateTime::getTimestamp`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Answer (score 4):

Try strtotime ( http://www.php.net/strtotime )

Comment: Only works with accepted date formats, which the input is not.

Answer (score 0):

use strtotime() and put it back in the date function like this:

date("l, F d, Y",strtotime($YOUR_MD_DATE));

Regards,
Dennis M.